# Designing a CNN for object position recognition in images

Tags: conv-neural-network

I'd like to detect the position of an object (e.g. a book's cover) into an image taken from a webcam. I would only need to output 4 points corresponding to the cover's corners into the image.

I was thinking of using CNNs (perhaps a variant on vgg-16?) and output 5 neurons: one for the probability of the cover being there (trained to be 1 in case there is, 0 in case there isn't) and the other 4 being the 2D-coordinate corners in the image.

Is this a decent approach to detect an object's position within an image?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this would work.

I assume your inputs will be the pixels of the image. Therefore, your dataset will consists of instances with inputs as the pixels and 5 output labels. Be warned that a CNN will need a lot of training data which means you will need to get 1000s of images of books and label them manually. Maybe you can use some weaker template techniques (old school image segmenting techniques) to label them automatically, and then you can correct them as you see fit, from this point you will be set to train your CNN.