# Object localization with CNN

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection

I am interested in locating the center of a playing card on the surface of a table:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I have written a script so that I can generate images like this, where the card is moved around and rotated. My idea was to generate 10,000 images and train a CNN on them. The CNN would be provided the image as input and the coordinates of the center of the card as output. I have tried several different architectures, such as

```
NetChain[{
  ConvolutionLayer[32, 3], Ramp,
  ConvolutionLayer[32, 3], Ramp,
  PoolingLayer[2, 2],
  ConvolutionLayer[64, 3], Ramp,
  ConvolutionLayer[64, 3], Ramp,
  PoolingLayer[2, 2],
  FlattenLayer[],
  LinearLayer[128], Ramp,
  LinearLayer[2]
  },
 "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image", {300, 225}, "Grayscale"}],
 "Output" -> 2
 ]
```

The code is written in Wolfram Language but should be self-explanatory. `Ramp` is the `ReLu` function. The pooling layers are max pooling layers. Linear layers are fully connected layers. I have also tried other architectures and different numbers of neurons. The loss function that I use is the mean squared error. The input has been normalized to the range [0, 1]. Output has been normalized and not normalized, it makes no difference.

My networks don't improve over time except for a not nearly large enough improvement in the very beginning, where essentially the network just learns to output values in the correct range. They remain as useless as they were to begin with, why? What can I do to solve this problem?

Ultimately, I would like to find the corners of the card. Finding the center is a first step towards this goal. This is also part of an even larger problem with more complicated images, which is why I'm trying to use a CNN instead of simpler methods which could surely work on this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You may look into Fully Convolutional Neural Networks for Image Segmentation:
https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf

Basically it does pixel wise classification using a hour-glass shaped CNN architecture. Each output pixel gives the region it belongs to as the result of the training, given an input image. But you would need pixel-wise annotation of the images. I think you can do that easily since you do generate the images by yourself and know where the cards are located in a pixel-correct fashion.

Comment: I would like to ask you the same that I asked Jan and Tonca. I'm looking to get a better understanding of why a plain CNN cannot be used for this problem.

Comment: A plain CNN is either trained for regression or classification. If you train it for classification, it will try to guess the class of the object in the given image. In your case, a very large portion of the image belongs to the table background and the discriminative information conveyed by the card is small. Alternatively, you can build it as a regressor to detect the corners of a card on the table. If you are going to have only a single card on the table, this may also work.

Comment: I am training it as a regressor. As you can see in my architecture, I output two elements. These are x and y coordinates of the center. There is no difference between this and detecting corners, but still, it does not work. This is what I'm looking for feedback on: Why does it not work?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good approach. CNN are known for being insensitive to the position of the patterns in the image. This is related in particular to the pooling layers.

I think that you should rather try some image segmentation technique, which is still based on CNN, but adds more layers of processing.

Comment: But CNNs are routinely used to output bounding boxes for objects? Cats, dogs etc. How is this different? Also, this answer seems to contradict [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278859/184870) answer.

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/image-segmentation-with-mask-r-cnn-ebe6d793272) is just an example of how image segmentation can be achieved. It is not sufficient to apply plain a CNN, it can only tell you wether there is or not a card in the image.

Comment: Thank you. When I look at networks used for face landmark detection, I see that many are plain CNNs. Why does it work for that problem?

Comment: Can you give any example?

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.00977.pdf) and [this trained network](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Vanilla-CNN-for-Facial-Landmark-Regression). [This one](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/2D-Face-Alignment-Net-Trained-on-300W-Large-Pose-Data) is also a normal CNN, although it can be hard to see on that page, and the architecture is a bit more advanced. [Here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/3D-Face-Alignment-Net-Trained-on-300W-Large-Pose-Data) is the same net used for the 3D case.

Comment: You were right, I've never seen this kind of model, I'm sorry for the wrong answer. In this case I would try to remove remove some pooling layers

Answer (score 1):

**I think [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/326887/163572) on another, [related question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326875/can-object-detection-be-done-by-passing-parts-of-images-to-an-image-classificati) should be a good starting point for you.**

Shortly, there are many neural network based methods specifically tailored for **object detection**; *"Single shot object detector (SSD)"*, *"(Fast(er)) Region-CNN (R-CNN)"*, *"You Only Look Once (YOLO (9000))"*, just to name a few.

There are many tutorials describing how they works, they have open implementations, and they are well described in respective articles. I recommend you having a look at those and start from there, rather than developing/coding your own network. These methods are perfect for the task that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you. I knew about these, but nevertheless, it is good to have it confirmed that these are good for the job. Do you know the answer to the question I asked Tonca, namely why plain CNN works well for face landmark detection and not for my test case? This is why I decided to try plain CNN in the first case. Since I don't need multiobject detection it seemed straightforward and computationally cheap to just do what the face landmark detection networks do. (I posted examples of face landmark detection networks in a comment to Tonca.)

Answer (score 1):

This should ideally be a comment but I don't have enough reputation.
I faced a similar problem with a single object localization data set. I did try regressing modified ResNet-18 (with 4 outputs) with the true label. I could achieve efficiency of around 83% after 30 epochs of training. The best efficiency was around 93%.

My thinking was that the multiple image detection and classification pipelines such as RCNN's use a region proposal method under classification/bounding box regression so in the case of a single image localization we could do without the region proposal method.

Two things could improve the efficiency:
1. Removing the GAP layer in the end
2. Replacing L2 loss with L1 loss